# Java Triangle Code with descending numbers

Tags: java

so i'm having a little issue with my code for my class.

my code looks like this:

```
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;

    System.out.println("Please enter a number 1...9 : ");
    n = scnr.nextInt();

    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int l = n;
    String space = " ";
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (k = i; k < n; k++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (j = i; j > 0; --j) {
            System.out.print(j + "");       

            }
        System.out.println("");

        }
```

my output looks like

-----1

---21

-321

4321

and my expected output is supposed to look like this:

-----1

--2-1

3-2-1

(assume the '-' are spaces)

I just need spaces between the numbers, but every time I do so, I get a full on triangle. If anyone could help me out with this I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: You need to clarify what you currently get as output, and what you would like to get as output.

Comment: Please clarify this, as well as your expected output, in the question itself.  It might also help you to give your variables more useful names than `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` and `n`.

Comment: What keeps you from just printing the space after the numbers?

Comment: Nothing keeps me from printing the spaces in between the numbers. But once I add them, the pattern loses its form and becomes a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I understand you wish to put spaces between the numbers that the user selects. So an example output would be:

```
Please enter a number 1...9 : 
9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

If this is what you want, then just do this:

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter a number 1...9 : ");
int n = scnr.nextInt();
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. my expected output has to look like a left triangle.

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong, what you did you just missed the right places to add a space. I formatted you for loops so that the numbers are displayed in an right angle. For your information you can define the variables in the for loop for(int i .... ) this makes it easier to read. Here is the version with the spaces.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int k = i; k < n; k++) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        for (int j = i; j > 0; --j) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenting the digit with an empty String.  If you concatenate a single space then you will generally get the output you want.  You will have a trailing space.  This is unlikely to be an issue.

You defined a `space` variable you probably intended to use as a constant for this construction.  It conventional to mark constants final and use an all-caps name.

```
final String SPACE = " ";
...
for (j = i; j > 0; --j) {
   System.out.print(j + SPACE);       
}
```

An alternative is to us a StringJoiner to compose the String and then output the String.

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(SPACE);
for (j = i; j > 0; --j) {
  joiner.add(j);
}
System.out.println(joiner.toString());
```